# Sorting numbers and text at one time creates issues

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, macros

I have an issue. I am filtering from a big product table (with about 32'000 rows) the products that I need and sort it first by the product name and then by the delivery number.

My issue is, that if I wanna filter and sort numbers as product names (which is also possible), it does not sort correctly (see picture).

[Picture of the filtered and sorted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpMS4.png)

My code is this one:

```
'*************************************************************
'Filter Product Code
Set myrange = Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

For Each c In myrange
    If Len(c.Value) <> 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Columns("A:D").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, _
            Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow), Sheet1.Range("G1"), False
    End If
Next

'Sheet1.Range("51:100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes

'*******************************************************************
'Sort the filtered list first by Product Code then by the Delivery number
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRowMax As Long
Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

With Sheet1

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

Range("G2:J" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("G2:G" & lastrow), _
 Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("I2:I" & lastrow), _
 Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
lngRowMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

End With
```

How can I proceed to have it sorted correctly. First the same product codes, then by the delivery number (ascending) as I want to sell the oldest products first.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Are the cell formats of data rows 4 and 5 different from the others? Just using the Sort function on the Data ribbon, it sorts as you expect for me.

Comment: It has to be done with a macro. The column G is formatted as text, colum I is formatted as number. I think that shouldn't be an issue, right? Still doesn't work. Any ideas @PeterT, @user3598756?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the solution for it. Only a small adjustment. The code for the sorting looks as follows now:

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRowMax As Long
Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

 With Sheet1

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

Range("G1:J" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("G1:G" & lastrow), _
   Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("I1:I" & lastrow), _
   Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers


Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
lngRowMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

End With
```